# Is it possible to install theme engines? If so, how?

Tags: gnome, themes

Sorry if this is a stupid question I am new to Linux.

I recently discovered what a theme engine is and I was wondering if it's possible to install other engines on my computer. A few themes that I have downloaded require certain engines. I am running GNOME 3.4 on Ubuntu. How can I find out what engines I have/where are they located and how would I add more?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you could run the following two simulations:

```
apt-get install -s gtk3-engines*
```

and

```
apt-get install -s gtk2-engines*
```

These commands should indicate engines available to you.

Then you could run:

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/installed-software
```

to get a list of software installed on your system and search that file for `engines`. I did that and have just the following engines because my OS is Lubuntu 12.10 and I haven't installed any extra themes:

> gtk2-engines:i386
>   gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
>   gtk3-engines-unico

You may also want to look at [basic theme engines for GTK+](https://launchpad.net/gtk-engines):

> GTK-engines is a collection of basic theme engines for GTK+.
>
> The GTK-engines provide basic themes for GTK. Themes control the user
>   interface, providing icons, shadows, text layout, color schemes,
>   window decoration and more.
>
> The basic theme engines are the ones that GNOME produce, though users
>   can install (or write and install) others.
>
> The basic theme engines are very flexible, so many themes can use a
>   single engine but still get a unique look and feel.

And from reading here and there, I get the impression that one has to be a little careful in ensuring that the themes one tries matches the GNOME version!

As for where exactly the "engines" are located, I honestly don't know but you could see if you have something like `/usr/share/gtk-engines` and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/`.

Comment: Thank you! that was very informative, how does one go about installing a new engine, is there a specific folder that they should be placed in? Also when i ran dpkg --get slections ... nothing happened :-\ does this mean i dont have any?

Comment: Did you really type `dpkg --get slections` because that is wrong. You need to type dpkg --get-selections, etc. The command line is unforgiving!

Comment: Even though I've been using Linux for a couple of years, I haven't found the need to install engines separately and so other than pointing you to resources, I'm afraid I can't be of more help. Sorry! If you are more forthcoming about which exact engine you wish to install along with where you've come across the suggestion that you should install them, I or someone may be able to say something specific.

Comment: no i typed it correctly, sorry for the typo i'll fix it...but earlier today the theme i had installed wasnt showing up now it, after restarting a few times. I will repost a question when the time comes thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just for completeness, you say you entered the dpkg command correctly and **nothing happened**. That is often a **good thing**. In this case, the command, as I provided it, should **silently** write the output not to screen but to your desktop! So you may not see anything happen unless you look on your desktop for a file called `installed-software`.